# Convergence in measure of exp

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show $f_n(x):= e^{-n \vert 1 - \sin x \vert}$ converges in measure to $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

So I want show that for $\epsilon >0$, and as $n$ tends to $\infty$ we have that

$$m(\{x \in [a,b] : \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert > \epsilon \})< \epsilon.$$

Just realized I have two $\epsilon$'s. My idea, we know that
$$e^{-n \vert 1 - \sin x \vert} > \epsilon$$

Then I can take a natural log and I get
$$\ln e^{-n \vert 1 - \sin x \vert} > \ln \epsilon$$

Then I get

$$-n \vert 1 - \sin x \vert > \ln \epsilon$$

Then I get

$$\vert 1 - \sin x \vert < \frac{1}{n} \ln \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

Can I then say $\sin x = 1$ only when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ plus integer values multiples of $2 \pi$. I get stuck here, so for each of these $x$ values does there correspond a ball that gets small as $n$ gets big? So then for each $n$ could I define these balls as $B_{r_n}(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n)$ where the $r_n$ tend to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

AHHH I just realized, there's only finitely many balls since my interval is finite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the full space is $X$ and your measure is $\mu$, then pointwise $\mu$-a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure if $\mu(X)<\infty$. Here, $\mu = m$, the Lebesgue measure, and $X = [a,b]$, so $m(X) < \infty$. Thus you need only show that you have pointwise a.e. convergence, which you clearly have, since $f_n(x)\to 0$ so long as $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$.